# FFT Images and its Inverse

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, fft

I have 256x256 image array (named `Mydata`) and I applied FFT transformation as   `fftshift(log1p(abs(fft2(Mydata))));`

How to inverse the transformation and image the results in MATLAB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fully reconstruct the image you will also need the phase.  If you recall the properties of the Fourier Transform, you can decompose any signal into its magnitude and phase counterparts.  What you have in this code is just the magnitude.  Without the phase, you cannot faithfully reconstruct your signal.  As such, you'll need to store the phase somewhere.  Remember that any complex number `num` can be represented in Euler form, such that:

```
 num <-> abs(num)*exp(j*angle(num));
```

`abs` is the magnitude of `num` and `angle` is the phase of `num`.  Now, supposing you stored the magnitude and phase:

```
  magData = abs(MyData);
  phaseData = angle(MyData);
```

Coincidentally, `angle` is the MATLAB function that determines the phase of every element in a complex-valued matrix.  To achieve the inverse operation, you would simply reverse the operations that you did above to achieve the original image:

```
  ifft2(expm1(ifftshift(magData.*exp(j*phaseData))));
```

`expm1` is the MATLAB operation that performs the inverse of `log1p`.